# Sufficient conditions for absolute continuity of a distribution function

Tags: probability, random-variable, conditional-probability, measure-theory

Consider two random variables $X,Z$ defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Assume

**1)** Let $\mathcal{Z}$ denote the support of $Z$. For any $z\in \mathcal{Z}$, the support of $X$ conditional on $Z=z$ is a set $\mathcal{A}_z$ with strictly positive Lebesgue measure.

**2)** The support of $X$ is a set $\mathcal{A}$ with strictly positive Lebesgue measure.

**3)** For any $z\in \mathcal{Z}$, the distribution of $X$ conditional on $Z=z$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure with everywhere positive density on $\mathcal{A}_z$.

Question: Do 1),2),3) imply that the distribution of $X$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure with everywhere positive density on $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean by a distribution being "strictly positive over some measurable set," because by definition all distributions (set-valued functions) have the value $1$ on the measurable set $\Omega$.  I wonder whether a mixture of a bivariate Normal distribution and a singular Normal distribution supported on $(Z,X)\in\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}$ might satisfy (1) - (3).

Comment: I have edited my question, does it make more sense now? Thank you

Comment: Thank you.  It looks like the example I provided is relevant to your question, then.

Comment: Thanks @whuber, could you help more if you have time? thank you

Comment: I don't understand which is the marginal distribution of $X$ according to your example. Thank you